# Quanta switch not resolving addresses

Tags: switch, network, dns

I've got this brand new Quanta T3048.
I've configured the VLANs we need but it came to my attention that the switch won't resolve any address even though I've set it (according to the configuration guide) to relay DNS packets to the actual dns we are using.

I'd like to stress that it's the switch (from its console) that doesn't resolve anything, and not hosts connected to its ports. For example I've got hosts connected to ports assigned to vlan10 that successfully obtain dhcp settings and resolve everything as it should.

This isn't really an issue. It's mostly curiosity on my side, since I'm not that familiar with Quanta appliances.

Here's a snipping from the guide that I'm following:

```
(Switch) #config
(Switch) (Config)#ip helper enable
(Switch) (Config)#interface vlan 10
(Switch) (if-vlan10)#ip helper-address 192.168.40.35 dhcp
(Switch) (if-vlan10)#ip helper-address 192.168.40.35 domain
(Switch) (if-vlan10)#exit
```

I've done this for the default vlan and additional one being used by a department. Here's my running config:

```
interface vlan 1
ip address 192.168.13.9 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address xx.xx.xx.xx domain
exit



interface vlan 40
ip address 192.168.xx.x 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address xx.xx.xx.xx domain
ip helper-address xx.xx.xx.xx dhcp
exit
```

I'm configuring the switch on 192.168.13.9, obviously I've added **helper-address** to relay to our router. I can successfully ping the router, but the switch isn't resolving anything :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch doesn't use the DNS relaying itself. Instead you need to use

```
ip name-server <IPaddr>
```

to set the switch's DNS server. Seems duplicate but the relay is for the clients and the `dns` for the upstream DNS server for the switch itself.